# Generate JWT Key pairs

Tags: jwt, rsa, key-pair

I'm new to JWT. I've noticed that a lot of people place the private and public keys in separate files, and then load the content of the files when creating the JWT.
For example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const privateKEY  = fs.readFileSync('./private.key', 'utf8');
const publicKEY  = fs.readFileSync('./public.key', 'utf8');

let token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions);
```

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the concept of something but doesn't that make every key the same? And what is the point of having keys if they're all the same? Let's say I'm creating a server that stores a user's login information and assigns a private and public key to each user. That would mean that ever key-pair would have to be unique right? I obviously want the keys to be generated automatically for each user. What is the correct way to create an unique key-pair for a user when using JWT?

Comment: the key(s) are only known by the server. It uses it to encrypt and decrypt the token signature so that no one can tamper with it. You don't hand those out to the client. You just send the encoded payload with encrypted & encoded signage. So its fine to use the same key for all tokens. Only when you have something like a third party identity provider,  then each server that uses this third party provider would get their own key pairs. So that not company a can issue tokens for company b.

Comment: You can maybe have a look at my demo project https://github.com/bluebrown/jwt-exchange-authentication